# Como copiar um array de objetos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Eu possuo um array de objetos e preciso criar uma função que recebe este array e retorna um novo array e com novos objetos modificados. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function increase_age(users) {
    for (user of users) {
        user.age ++;
    }
    
    return users;
}

const users = [{name: "Lucas", age: 21}, {name: "Maria", age: 23}];
const new_array = increase_age(users);
```

No exemplo acima, os objetos de `users` também são alterados após a chamada da função.

O que eu quero é fazer uma cópia desses objetos para que sejam alterados sem afetar os objetos originais. Como posso fazer isso em JavaScript puro?

Comment: Caro Jean copie como as sugestões que lhe linkei e altere depois o que tiver que alterar.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, eu não tinha encontrado essa questão no site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar o `map`, retornando um novo objeto literal em cada iteração:

```js
function increaseAge(users) {
  return users.map((user) => ({
    ...user,
    age: user.age + 1
  }));
}

const users = [{name: "Lucas", age: 21}, {name: "Maria", age: 23}];
const newArray = increaseAge(users);
console.log(newArray);
```

Mudei os nomes da convenção de nomenclatura de `snake_case` para `camelCase`, que é a convenção mais usada no JavaScript.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, ajudou bastante :)